# File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module __import__(name) ImportError: No module named django

Tags: python, django, module

Here is my INSTALLED_APPS in settings

INSTALLED_APPS = (

```
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.admin',
`'mongoengine.django.mongo_auth'`,
'django.contrib.formtools',
```

)

First django dependencies can be solved smoothly. It comes the problem when processing `'mongoengine.django.mongo_auth'`. When I print out the `name` in **import**(name) in /usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/**init**.py. The result is 'mongoengine.django'. I am pretty sure that django and mongoengine module is successfully installed.

So what the problem is? BTW, I use sudo to install module 
sudo pip install

Otherwise, it can not be installed because the modules are located in the root file directory.

Comment: check the extra quotation mark on your code, around `'mongoengine.django.mongo_auth'`. They shouldn't be there

Comment: Have you activated your virtual environment?

Comment: @JaquelinePassos They're called *backticks*, btw. Anyways, you've got a really sharp pair of eyes there. :)

Comment: Yeah. The backticks are used for emphasis. I added them. It's not the problem.

Comment: BTW, I am using virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. New mongoengine did some modification.

`pip uninstall mongoengine`

and then install the older version

`pip install mongoengine==0.9.0`